# Huawei Appgallery Publishing Problem - Manifest Warnings

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to upload an APK file to Huawei App gallery and after submitting it to review i got this result with two warnings

https://i.stack.imgur.com/agQWz.jpg

FIRST Warning :
Incorrect adaptive devices. Check whether the configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml file is compatible with watch apps.

SECOND Warning :
Incorrect adaptive devices. Check whether the configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml file is compatible with VR apps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="@@@@">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/GreenActionBarTheme">


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks it was not a big problem because they accepted my app 3 days later .. So you just need to be patient !